# Reusability of mappers

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is mapstruct the right tool for generating multiple models by reusing mapping code ?

Example, I have a single input class:

```
public class MySource {
 private String props;
}
```

and different target classes

```
public class FooClass {
  private String foo;
}

public class BarClass {
  private String bar;
}
```

and mappers

```
public abstract class FooClassMapper {
  @Mapping(source = "props", target = "foo")
  public abstract FooClass mapFoo(MySource source)
}

public abstract class BarClassMapper {
  @Mapping(source = "props", target = "bar")
  public abstract BarClass mapBar(MySource source)
}
```

Is there a way to avoid having multiple mappers by using MappingConfig, inheritance, or other ways ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare multiple (different) mapping methods in a single interface, e.g.

```
@Mapper
public interface MySourceMapper {
  @Mapping(...)
  FooClass mapToFoo(MySource source);

  @Mapping(...)
  BarClass mapToBar(MySource source);
}
```

Comment: This is ine way to do this. Another option is to use `Mapper#uses`

Comment: @Filip `Mapper.uses` does not solve the OP's request to *avoid* having multiple mappers; you'd still need two mappers, even though one can make use of the other.

Comment: You are right @JimmyB, I missed that part. The OP didn't try anything with uses, that's why I mentioned it as well. Maybe someone else would be interested in that